# Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/v1/mega/building from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: java, node.js, angular, spring

it's my first time using Java backend and angular front end.
I'm trying to build and run this project but I'm having this error:
"[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/v1/mega/building from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED)"

I ran .\gradlew.bat build to build the Java Application and the run npm install and npm run start on the angular and node js code..

Do I have to start the Java server in some way after building the project?

Here is my code:

main.java

```
import com.nortal.mega.persistence.BuildingRepository;
import com.nortal.mega.persistence.entity.BuildingDbo;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.event.ApplicationReadyEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;

import java.util.Arrays;

@AllArgsConstructor
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    private final BuildingRepository buildingRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
```

proxy.conf.json
I have tried changing the target to 127.0.0.1, [::] all to no avail

```
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "loglevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your backend is just not running. To start a spring boot application:

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

from the root of your java application

edit:
Looks like you are on Windows, so it would be something like

```
.\gradlew.bat bootRun
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, It worked!

Comment: Do you have any documentations, pdfs or videos on Java Spring and angular that you can recommend for me?

Comment: I don't know much about angular. For any problems I encounter in Spring Boot, this website: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot usually have high quality tutorials. Spring's documentation is also very thorough, so if you want to learn more details after going through the tutorials, you can read the official documentation.

Comment: Okay, thanks

I'll have a look